# IE8 not recalculating size of div on insertion of content

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

So, now in this page (it's a dev page), http://www.antarctic-design.co.uk/oboe when the content is loaded (dynamically from JSON source), IE doesn't recalculate the size. Do you know how to force it to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with

```
.information_block { height: auto; }
```

you should solve (or at least it works injecting that style using development tools [F12])